# Comparing DataGridView values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application in C # that registers support tickets in a DataGridView, each ticket has a status, which may be pending or completed. I want to implement a method to validate if a ticket is completed, then this record can not be modified. What i tried was to compare the value of the cell in each row for the Status column of the DataGridView with a string and if they were equal disable a button that updates the registry values. I know it must have other ways, but I'm a rookie.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in DataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (rows.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Equals("Completed"))
            {
                btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

This is what I tried, but does nothing. Could you help me with this? Or give me some suggestions on how to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Can you explain more about this button? I assume you have multiple rows and only 1 button? Maybe you mean to only looks at Cell 10 in the "Current" row as opposed to every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the RowEnter event:

```
private void DataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  btnUpdate.Enabled=!DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().Equals("Completed") ;  
}
```

Perhaps, the following is required just after having filled the gridview
*(I don't remember if the RowEnter event is raised or not at initialisation).*

```
btnUpdate.Enabled=DataGridView1.CurrentRow!=null &&
  !DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Equals("Completed")
```